# Refrigerator/freezer

Tags: refrigerator

The cooling fan only runs when the freezer door is open. When it is closed it stops running. Therefore the bottom of the freezer is frozen but the top is luke warm. The same with the refrigerator.  Any help?

Comment: Brand and model? Some are the other way is this a recent change or was some work done or new ?

Comment: Make, model? sounds like it is possible someone at assembly plant put 2 wires on a 3 terminal microswitch on the wrong pair... Has it always done this, since it was new? Possibly an easy fix (maybe).